# Call protected function in main class

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class account
    {
    private:
    int accountNumber;
    string accountName;

    enter code here`protected:
    void setAccountNumber(int aNum);
    void setAccountName(string aName);

    public:
    account(int accNum, string accName);
    account();
    };

    void account::setAccountNumber(int aNum)
    {
    accountNumber = aNum;
    }

    void account::setAccountName(string aName)
    {
    accountName = aName;
    }

    account::account()
    {
    accountNumber = 0;
    accountName = "Null";
    accountBalance = 0.0;
    }

    account::account(int accNum, string accName)
    {
    accountNumber = accNum;
    accountName = accNum;
    accountBalance = 0.0;
    }

    int main()
    {
    account a1;
    a1.setAccountNumber(100001);
    a1.setAccountName("Zunain Shareef");

    return 0;
    }
```

What is wrong with this code? I cant call protected methods? I'm very new.

Comment: This is the _purpose_ of it. Why not look up the term `protected` in your textbook, and study the resulting page?

Comment: What is the sense of "=============================="?

Comment: @Klaus Most likely OP was told that there is too much code in his post and that more non-code needs to be added. I.e. it is cheating around the system attempting to force some of the missing explanation and details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't.

The protected accessor on a method means that only the following can access it:

- the class itself
- class that inherits from it
- another class with friendship

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access